# Obtener tiempo de llegada google maps api javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, google-maps

Tengo un mapa el cual calcula con este método de google directionsService.route, con ese método se devuelve un response. Solo quiero es poder obtener el tiempo calculado por google.

```js
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var request = {
        origin:{lat:latitudUsuario,lng:longitudUsuario},
        destination: {lat:9.95,lng:-67.39},
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode['DRIVING'],
        unitSystem: google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem['METRIC'],
        provideRouteAlternatives: true
       };
       directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
           directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
           directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
         }else{
           alert("No existen rutas entre ambos puntos");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo actual

Comment: @WilmerMorgado edita tu pregunta y ahí agrégale ese código!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba hacer lo siguiente. Justo debajo de la llamada:

```
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

Agrega este codigo:

```
    // Obtener la duración para la primer ruta
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var duration = 0;

    // Iteramos todos los legs de la ruta
    route.legs.forEach(function (leg) {
      // Sumamos la duracion de cada uno
      // La duración esta en segundos.
      duration += leg.duration.value;
    });

    // Por ejemplo: imprimimos el resultado en DOMElement con id 'duracion'
    document.getElementById('duracion').innerHTML = duration + ' segundos';
```

Dejo una demo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/0po00agp/

Mas info aqui: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es